# Char transmission using Virtualwire RF signal

Tags: arduino-uno, rf, remote-control

This is a really basic problem, but I haven't been able to resolve it myself and would really appreciate the help.  So I've been struggling for a few weeks now to set up RF communication between two arduino uno chips.  I have the transmitter and receiver hooked up to 5V supply, with the data pins connected to digital pin 4.  My code looks like this:

Transmitter code:

```
#define rfTransmitPin 4  //RF Transmitter pin = digital pin 4
#define ledPin 13        //Onboard LED = digital pin 13

unsigned int data = 0;  // variable used to store transmission data

void setup(){
  pinMode(rfTransmitPin, OUTPUT);     
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600);   
}

void loop(){
  digitalWrite (rfTransmitPin, HIGH);
  data = digitalRead (rfTransmitPin); // Read the digital transmitter pin
  Serial.println(data);
  digitalWrite (ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(2000);

  digitalWrite (rfTransmitPin, LOW);
  data = digitalRead (rfTransmitPin); // Read the digital transmitter pin
  Serial.println(data);
  digitalWrite (ledPin, LOW);
  delay(2000);
  }
```

Receiver code:

```
#define rfReceivePin 4  //RF Receiver pin = digital pin 4
#define ledPin 13        //Onboard LED = digital pin 13

unsigned int data = 0;   // variable used to store received data

void setup(){
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rfReceivePin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  data=digitalRead(rfReceivePin);    //listen for data on Digital Pin 4

   if(data = HIGH){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   //If a HIGH signal is received, turn LED ON
    Serial.println(data);
  }

  if(data = LOW){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);   //If a LOW signal is received, turn LED OFF
    Serial.println(data);
  }
}
```

This should be really simple, but for some reason I'm reading a continual HIGH signal from the receiver module.  I'm trying to sort out the basic functionality of the RF tx-rx pair before developing code to send a char using the Virtual Wire library, but I can't even get it to function at this level.  Since my code is so basic I'm convinced it must be a hardware issue and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

VIf you using Virutalwire try exemple in the library. 
You can't send simple digitata data with Rf.
Best Regards Mikael

[link Virutalwire](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/VirtualWire/index.html)

Comment: Hi Mikael, thanks for the reply.  I've tried running the example transmitter/receiver code, and all I get is the setup printout on the serial monitor, the message doesn't come through.

Comment: http://www.hackshed.co.uk/rf-communication-between-2-arduinos/

Comment: This will you show you how you use VirutalWire

Comment: Turned out to be a faulty receiver, it's all working as it should be now :-)

Comment: Glad you got it working